# Facing IllegalStateException : Error processing condition when using spring-boot 2.7

Tags: spring-boot, illegalstateexception, arraystoreexception

I am migrating spring-boot version 2.7.17. I am getting below error when I run application.

```
Application run failed java.lang.IllegalStateException : Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration
   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)



Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException:sun.reflect.annotation.TypenotPresentExceptionProxy
```

How can I resolve this so that my application will run.

Comment: Please share your pom.xml or build.gradle file. It seems `spring-boot-starter-web-services` dependency is not included.

Comment: I added spring-boot-starter-web-services dependency and tried. Still same error.

Comment: Please prepare sample code which reproduce the issue and share.